# Programmatically fetch user's last login date to G Suite

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace, google-reporting-api

On a user's page on the G Suite admin console, an admin can see the last login of a user. For example, one user I can see has a "last login" date of two years ago.

I'm trying to pull this date programatically. However, the Reports API that provides information on login events only goes back [180 days](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-login). How is Google getting this login date, and can it be fetched via API?

Comment: If you have checked the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-login), this feature is limited for lawful purposes with consent of the your customer. Also, it was stated that the maximum period you can get is only 180 days from the current. And by using the `GET` HTTP request and include the authorization token described in the [authorization documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/authorizing.html), you will be able to retrieve all logins for all of your domain's services but only for 180 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow missed this before, but you can get the last login date/time with the User Usage Report (rather than the Login Activity report).

API docs are [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/userUsageReport/get) and the App Script example I'm using is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-reports#generate_user_usage_report). I realized that if GAM was pulling the information there had to be an API for it.

Answer (score 1):

Google has this information because they are logging the event when it happens and storing that to present in the admin console. If you start to build an application now and start storing those events as time passes you too will have a date that goes back years. G Suite Enterprise customers can seamlessly do this if they [Set up BigQuery logs in the Admin console](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9079365).

You should be able to get this information now though. Look at the following APIs used in GAMADV-XTD you can get this info with this command for example.

```
gam report users parameters accounts:last_login_time filters "accounts:last_login_time<#filtertime#" filtertime -5y
```

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/customerUsageReports
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/userUsageReport

Comment: I tried that GAM command and got back 28 users out of several hundred - and they all said "last login: never". I know a few accounts that weren't listed logging in more frequently than that (myself included).

Comment: Is there or was there any 3rd party IdP attached to the domain for authentication? Usually that would be a reason or the account is new or a service account perhaps

Comment: We don't use a third-party IdP, just using the default Google login.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood how the filtering worked this - this solution works.